# WCF Web Service - List<> Return type

Tags: c#, wcf

```
List<CertMail> lsRecipetNumber = new List<CertMail>();
```

`CertMail` class is in data access layer which returns a `List<CertMail>`. I need to
convert this to the object of my class and return that

```
List<CertMailReceiptNumbers> lsReceiptNumbers = new List<CertMailReceiptNumbers>();


CertMailReceipt.lsCMRN = lsReceiptNumbers; //---- > return this.
```

How do i add all the rows in the `CertMail` list to `CertMailRecieptNumbers` and return that from `CertMailRecieptNumbers` class?

Comment: Can you show us what `CertMail` and `CertMailReceipt` look like? Are the almost the same?

Comment: CertMail and CertMailReceipt are not similar , CertMailReceipt is my data contract class and CertMail is CertMail is the class in data access layer which returns a list<certmail>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your need it's a simple mather of mapping from one to another.

Well you need to go throu your CertMail list and then for each of them create a new CertMailReceiptNumbers

Ex.

```
...
lsReceiptNumber.ForEach(certMail => 
{
    lsReceiptNumbers.Add(convertToCertMailReceiptNumber(certMail));
});

return lsReceiptNumber
}

Public CertMailReceiptNumbers convertToCertMailReceiptNumber(CertMail cm) 
{
     var cmrn = new ertMailReceiptNumber();
     cmrn.xxx = cm.xxxx;
     ...;
     return cmrn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need to map from `CertMail` to `CertMailReceipt` and the two types are very similar, you could use an automagic helper like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) to help you with the mapping.

Basically, AutoMapper will handle much of the boring and error-prone left-right code - assigning one property on the target to a property on the source object.

In your case, if the two types are somewhat similar, you could do something like:

```
using AutoMapper;

Mapper.CreateMap<CertMail, CertMailReceipt>();

sourceList.ForEach(certMail => 
{
    lsReceiptNumbers.Add(Mapper.Map<CertMail, CertMailReceipt>(certMail))
});
```

or if you prefer:

```
using AutoMapper;

Mapper.CreateMap<CertMail, CertMailReceipt>();

foreach(certMail cm in sourceList)    
{
    lsReceiptNumbers.Add(Mapper.Map<CertMail, CertMailReceipt>(cm));
}
```

This is basically the same idea that NPayette mentioned, just using an half-automatic mapper, instead of having to write the whole mapping process yourself.

And with a bit of luck (and depending on your types of data structures), you might even get the benefit of Automapper being able to even map entire lists from one type to another:

```
lsReceiptNumbers = Mapper.Map<List<CertMail>,
                              List<CertMailReceipt>>(sourceList);
```

Automapper will go through the list of items itself, and apply its mapping to each item, and add those to the resulting output list.

Comment: I gave you +1, but similarly, what is with the `ForEach` lambda abuse today?  I'd be a lot more comfortable with this if it just used a plain old `foreach`.

Comment: @Aaronaught: that's really very much a personal preference - either way works. Plus with AutoMapper, you don't need either of the two, if your classes are similar enough :-)

Comment: I'm a fan of `.ForEach` if it lets you 1 line an operation or if you're using it to inline a side effecting operation